# Dynamic ID assigning

Tags: php

I have a problem with my page. I am displaying images using PHP Loop statement. Now I want to assign these images with different id's. Example first loop the first image displayed will have an id="img1", next loop and second image has id="img2". Numbers on the id changes based on the loop iteration variable, while "img" is constant. Here's my code:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
echo ("<img src='gangjeong.png' width='113' id='img'.$i>");
}
```

but it's not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I got it to work now, thanks for the answers. The working code is:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
echo ("<img src='gangjeong.png' width='113' id='img$i'>");
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what happens? Compiler errors, unforeseen behavior, etc. This is a good question, just are you being downvoted to oblivion for being a bit vague.

Comment: BTW, your 'working code' does not even hold your own requirements (you said `the first image displayed will have an id="img1"`) ;)

Comment: sorry, I gotta edit it.

Comment: @Clyde You have to use `i<=6`, otherwise you won't enumerate 6 times.

Comment: oh I see. so that's why it's missing one. Thanks so much for the ideas, and sorry for the errors on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use unescaped single quotes if you start your string by single quotes.

These are the possibilities you have:

- Using double quotes inside single quotes:

  ```
  for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    echo ('<img src="gangjeong.png" width="113" id="img' . ($i+1) . '" />');
  }
  ```
- Using escaped single quotes inside single quotes (**ugly**):

  ```
  for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    echo ('<img src=\'gangjeong.png\' width=\'113\' id=\'img' . ($i+1) . '\' />');
  }
  ```
- Using double quotes for starting/ending the string:

  ```
  for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    echo ("<img src='gangjeong.png' width='113' id='img" . ($i+1) . "' />");
  }
  ```
- Using escaped double quotes inside  double quotes (**ugly**):

  ```
  for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    echo ("<img src=\"gangjeong.png\" width=\"113\" id=\"img" . ($i+1) . "\" />");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes inside quotes are a no no without proper escaping. Also you have a missing `>` for the `img`  tag. This should do:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
echo "<img src='gangjeong.png' width='113' id='img".$i."'>";
}
```

Comment: You are appending after the close '. I believe you want it to be inside the ' '? 'img".$i."'

Comment: Cool, let me delete mine so we don't have duplicated answers

Answer (score 0):

Where's your escape characters? Your quotes need escaping, or put your HTML part in double quotes and PHP strings in single, or vice versa. Just make sure you're not confusing start and end quotes.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is not correct, use:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
echo '<img src="gangjeong.png" width="113" id="img'.$i.'" alt="">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
    echo "<img src=\"gangjeong.png\" width=\"113\" id=\"img$i\">";
}
```

Comment: This won't start with `img1`.